# Vector parameters in functions

Tags: r, function, vector, parameters

I need to define t be a 3d vector of repeated elements dependent on user input m i.e. t=c(m, m, m) and then use it the function:

```
b <- c(0.5,0.2,1)  
fn <- function(m) { sum(t-b) }
```

Is there a way for me to tell R that t is a 3d repeated vector with elements m?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rep()` function, for one option:

```
b <- c(0.5,0.2,1)

fn <- function(m, b) {
  t <- rep(m , 3)
  sum(t-b)
}

> fn(2, b)
[1] 4.3
```

You could rely on recycling in this case:

```
fn2 <- function(m, b) {
  sum(m-b)
}

> fn2(2, b)
[1] 4.3
```

where R automagically extends `m` to be of the correct length. This is dangerous though, especially if you don't do any checking to see if the length of `m` and `b` match.

A better version using `rep()` would be to not hardcode the length that `t` needs to be but to take that from `b`, as in:

```
fn3 <- function(m, b) {
  t <- rep(m , length(b))
  sum(t - b)
}

> fn3(2, b)
[1] 4.3
> b <- c(b, b) ## make `b` longer
> length(b)
[1] 6
> fn3(2, b)    ## fn3() still works
[1] 8.6
```

A note on you `fn()`; you refer to `b` *inside* the function but do not pass in `b` as an argument. Hence you are relying on R finding the right `b` in the global workspace. This is not good practice. Instead, pass in via arguments all objects needed within the function, as I did in my examples. You'll find errors easier to track down etc if you do it that way.

Comment: Thanks. I know this is a really basic question, but when you write fn3 on four separate lines, what is the benefit? Also how would you write it on a single line? (when I try single line, I get an error at the sum)

Comment: I spaced it out so it was easier to read, hence easier to understand, hence easier to debug. As far as R is concerned, you need each R statement on a separate line. In `fn3()` there are 2 statements, so two separate lines. There is an alternative, separate the two statements with `;` on a single line, as in: `t <- rep(m , length(b)); sum(t - b)` but why you'd want to do this is beyond me, especially as your code gets more complex. The `function()` call and the closing brace `{` don't need to be on separate lines at all, but I do so for ease of reading.